# Error creating resource "Azure Bot" via Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I tried to create an "Azure Bot" via Terraform using these instructions:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/bot_service_azure_bot

and recieved this error message:
[image]

To avoid any misunderstandings, this is the resource I would like to create via Terraform:
[image]

When I create the resource "Azure Bot" via portal, the microsoft_app_id is created automatically. Why does via Terraform the microsoft_app_id have to be assigned the client_id?

How can i solve the error "The Microsoft App ID is already registered to another bot application"?

Comment: `The Microsoft App ID is already registered to another bot application` error occurs when the same app ID is already registered with another bot application. Check and delete the existed one or try creating a new app registration and assign it to the bot resource. @emil

Comment: The only resource in this resource group is a web app. So the ID can't be registered to another app.

As far as I understood, the client_id can't be the app_id like here:   
microsoft_app_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.client_id.

I think I don't understand something fundamental here. Why isn't the microsoft_app_id created automatically, like via portal?
If I create the bot via portal there is no microsoft_app_id conflict, why is that?

Comment: Understood. Are you trying the same code as given in [terraform template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/bot_service_azure_bot). @emil

Comment: yes. it's the same code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also received the same error when trying to create a web bot servise with terraform.

*Two ways to resolve this conflict:*

***Approach-1:***

Firstly, you can use random `uuid` resource as given below to generate the unique app Id while creating the bot resource.

```bash
resource "random_uuid" "appid" {}
```

But the above one might also fail in some environments.

***Approach-2:***

To make it work effectively, I have registered a new app under `App registrations` as shown below and allocated it to my Azure web bot service instead of creating it automatically with `client_config`block.

[image]

Once it is done, I used the same one in my terraform code with the help of `variable` block as detailed below.

`main.tf`:

```bash
variable "microsoftappid" {
  type    = string
  default = "3072xxxxx8579"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Jahnavi"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights" "example" {
  name                = "jahsights"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

resource "azurerm_application_insights_api_key" "example" {
  name                    = "newapikey"
  application_insights_id = azurerm_application_insights.example.id
  read_permissions        = ["aggregate", "api", "draft", "extendqueries", "search"]
}

resource "azurerm_bot_service_azure_bot" "example" {
  name                = "jahazurebot"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "global"
  microsoft_app_id    = var.microsoftappid
  sku                 = "F0"

  endpoint                              = "https://example.com"
  developer_app_insights_api_key        = azurerm_application_insights_api_key.example.api_key
  developer_app_insights_application_id = azurerm_application_insights.example.app_id
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Reference:* [Terraform registry template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/bot_service_azure_bot)

Comment: many thanks @Jahnavi.
the primary goal for me was to save time when creating Azure Bot resources through automation via Terraform. since I have to create the app registration in the portal, I don't save any time. I thought the Azure Bot resource could be created just as quickly as a Web App, but I was wrong. :)